# JQuery Filtro Con CheckBox

Tags: c#, jquery

Tengo un programa en ASP.Net Core 6 con Entity Framework que trata de una tienda de artículos. Tengo un sidebar que está compuesto por checkbox que tienen las categorías (p.e. Nintendo o PlayStation).

El problema que tengo es que al apretar los dos checkboxes Nintendo y PlayStation, la vista parcial debería cargarse sólo con los productos de esas marcas, pero sin embargo está trayendo todos los artículos.

En el CSHTML genero el `forEach` para cargar las categorías. Luego en el script tomo los productos si está seleccionado al menos una categoría 1 trae los productos que tenga la data-categoría seleccionada. En este ejemplo, Nintendo o PlayStation.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#todasCheckbox').on('change', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.categoriaCheckbox').prop('checked', isChecked);
    filtrarProductos();
  });

  $('.categoriaCheckbox').on('change', function() {
    var allChecked = $('.categoriaCheckbox:checked').length === $('.categoriaCheckbox').length;
    $('#todasCheckbox').prop('checked', allChecked);
    filtrarProductos();
  });


  function filtrarProductos() {
    var selectedCategorias = [];
    $('.categoriaCheckbox:checked').each(function() {
      var categoriaId = $(this).data('categoria');
      selectedCategorias.push(categoriaId);
    });
    if (selectedCategorias.length === 0) {
      $('.productoItem').show();
    } else {
      $('.productoItem').hide();
      selectedCategorias.forEach(function(categoriaId) {
        $('.productoItem[data-categoria="' + categoriaId + '"]').show();
      })
    }
    var url = '@Url.Action("Productos", "Home")';
    var data = {
      pagina: @Model.PaginaActual,
      categoriaId: selectedCategorias.join(","),
      busqueda: '@Model.Busqueda'
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      data: data,
      success: function(result) {
        $('#productosContainer').html(result);
      },
      error: function(xht, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb" id="breadcrumb-container">

    </ol>
  </nav>

  <div class="row mb-3">
    <nav class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item active">Filtrar Resultados</li>
        <li class="list-group-item ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="todasCheckbox" data-categoria="" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="todasCheckbox">Todas</label>
        </li>
        @foreach (var categoria in ViewBag.Categorias) {

        <li class="list-group-item ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input categoriaCheckbox" id="categoriaCheckbox_@categoria.CategoriaId" data-categoria="@categoria.CategoriaId">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="categoriaCheckbox_@categoria.CategoriaId">@categoria.NombreCategoria</label>
        </li>
        }
      </ul>

      <div class="d-flex mb-3">
        <form action="@Url.Action(" Productos " , "Home ")" method="get">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">Ver Todos Los Productos</button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 pb-3">
      <div id="productosContainer">
        @Html.Partial("_ProductosPartial", Model)

      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agregar el Controller

Comment: Por favor, no escribas todo en mayúsculas, hace que el texto sea muy difícil de leer.